# Pg_dump from newer version (9.3.9) to pg_restore with an older version (9.1.13)

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump

I need to restore data from my newer postgres database to an older on another machine. I know pg_restore doesn't work with dumps from newer versions, but somehow I've got to get that data.

Acording to [this post](https://pgolub.wordpress.com/2013/11/19/dump-and-restore-of-postgresql-version-compatibility-faq/) there is a way but it involves manually modifying the rows that are different across versions, but there are no informations online what these differences are.

What is the possible fix for such problem? 
Is there any way to import data from newer to older postgres?

`psql db < dump | head` yields:

```
ERROR:  relation "cities" does not exist
invalid command \. 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1" 
LINE 1: 1 Kraków 0 0 2013-10-30 08:39:45.232006 2013-10-30 08:39:4....
```

And thousand more of these.

Comment: "for such problem" --- what problem? Is there a real problem you're experiencing at the moment?

Comment: This problem is described before and after that sentence. I don't get the point of your question

Comment: "but somehow I've got to get that data" --- you have got the data. So what is the problem then? The point is: you've stated you have dumped the data, at least that what you've said.

Comment: Ok I might have been unclear about that. I got the data dumped, but I can't import it to an older database

Comment: "I can't" --- it's not an issue explanation. Does the `psql` literally return `I CANNOT IMPORT THIS`?

Comment: If you use a plain text dump (aka "SQL Dump") you should be able to run that on the older server (provided you are not using any 9.3 only features like JSON datatype)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using a plain text dump. But unfortunately the database doesn't seem to be able to consume that.
And I'm not using any new features. I'll add an output to the question

Comment: If you already _have_ a plain text dump, then you need `psql` to "import" it, **not** `pg_restore`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name tried both, same result

Comment: "*relation "cities" does not exist*" indicates that there was a problem before doing the `copy` statement for `cities` which prevented that table to be created. So you need to search for that error

Comment: But the dump seems to work fine on my newer version of postgres. It imports without a single error

Comment: Have you tried to check if the `cities` is created? Or if it is even in the dump?

Comment: Show the **first** error message. `psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1` is useful. Assuming it's actually a version/compat problem, which we don't know yet, you'll need to use the 9.1.x version of pg_dump to dump it. If you only have a dump, restore to 9.3, then use 9.1's pg_dump to dump it again.

Comment: Given the table name *cities* : is there any postgis involved in the database ? ("create extension" was introduced somewhere between 9.0 and 9.3; before that you had to manually install the libs and run a couple of constructor/installation scripts.) Maybe the `create table cities` failed because of missing POSTGIS extension.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have any option to take dump (in higher version of Postgres) in custom, directory or tar format and to restore back (in lower version of Postgres).

But if we need to copy/move data from higher version of Postgres to lower version of Postgres we can do so by taking dump in plain format like below

> pg_dump -h <db-ip> -p <db-port> -U <db-user> -F p -f <backup-path> <db-name>

It will dump backup in plain sql queries that can be retored to any database (even in other than Postgres)

We can restore above plain format database backup in any version of Postgres as below

> psql --host <db-ip> --port <db-port> --username <db-user> --dbname <db-name> -f <backup-path>